# is_file function in php laravel returns false

Tags: php, laravel, file, filesystems, package

I downloaded a package from packagist with composer to my laravel project, the package is simply meant to fetch movie subtitles when i supply it a video file, but it keeps validating false everytime i upload a movie file, i dont know why, here is the php/laravel code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{


   $file = $request->movie;

   // dd($request);
    // $file = 'E:/Media/Jack reacher.mp4';

    if (empty($file)) {
        echo 'error! you must supply a file';

        return 1;
    }
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        echo 'error! file ' . $file . ' does not exist';

        return 2;
    }

    $config = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/config/configuration.yml.dist'));

    if (empty($config)) {
        echo 'error! config file does not exist';

        return 3;
    }

    $manager   = new SubtitlesManager($config['username'], $config['password'], $config['language']);
    $subtitles = $manager->get($file);

    if (!empty($subtitles) && !empty($subtitles[0])) {
        $fileGenerator = new FileGenerator();
        $fileGenerator->downloadSubtitle($subtitles[0], $file);
    } else {
        echo 'error! impossible to find the subtitle';
    }

}
```

it always returns an error saying

> error! file jackreacher.mp4 does not exist2

This particular condition keeps returning false

```
if (!is_file($file)) {
    echo 'error! file ' . $file . ' does not exist';

    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Would u provide the form code ?

Comment: Ah, this is quite embar.assing, I just saw the error. I didn't add the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to the form

Comment: Yes I was going to say that, that's why I asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this attribute to form.

This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```